# MultipleActiveResultSets=True not giving correct result while calling stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

When we set `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` and call a stored procedure, It gives bad data (Data is not mapped correctly in related columns) but when we don't include `MultipleActiveResultSets` in connection string then we are getting correct data.

How to fix or to know what is causing this issue?

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/h32h3abf%28v%3dvs.100%29

Comment: "How to fix"  Turn it off. "know what is causing this issue"  Sounds like a mishandling of the 'statement interleaving' that happens during MARS. Perhaps the .net version and sql version aren't perfectly aligned.

Comment: @Davesoft, I need to use it as i am using multiple data readers. What i want to understand is what could cause the bad data issue. I have tried it with Entity Framework, Dapper and ADO as well but issue is same in all of them.